# Finding the generating function of $d_n = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} d_k(n-k)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

This example is an exam question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287636/generating-function-of-a-convolution?rq=1

Is a similar example. This problem is solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate. What do you guys think?

Comment: Its the first time I ask a question here and I saw it was already solved. Shall I delete my question?